# Не обрабатываются мета-теги (og:image) для шеринга в facebook (share)

Tags: html, facebook, share

Прописал мета-теги в проекте, чтоб во время шеринга подтягивало нужную картинку. На facebook сначала подтягивало логотип, но в связи с изменениями разрешения на fb 1200*630 изменил картинку, но все равно подтягивает старый лого, вместо прописанной картинки... Вот код, который я использовал в heder... Почему у меня не подтягивает картинку из метатегов?

```
<html lang="en" >    
  <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#">

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <meta property="og:type" content="image/jpeg">
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mysite.com/images/faimage.jpg" >
    <meta property="og:url"  content="http://www.mysite.com/">
    <meta property="og:title"  content="my_site">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Something text">

    <meta property="og:image:type"  content="image/jpeg">
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" >
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="630" >
```

Отладка fb https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/ все ранво показывает:

```
Inferred Property     The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property     The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property     The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Share App ID Missing  The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog.
```

А мета-теги НЕ обрабатывает...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
    </head>
```

ЧТО мне нужно сделать, чтоб отображалась faimage.jpg во время шеринга?

Comment: У FB есть дебаггер https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ , с помощью которого можно обновить данные для шаринга. Попробуйте с помощью него перескрапить страницу.

Comment: Как я помню в `head` надо записать так
`<head  prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#"`.

А в `html` убрать то что связано с `og`

Comment: Razmik Galstyan, я меняю строку <head> на строку <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#"> . Сейчас попробую

Comment: Razmik Galstyan, сделал изменения.....все по-прежнему.....картинка не подтягивается...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дебаггер facebook (developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) при отладке показывает информацию отладки введенного сайта. Обработанный скрапером URL НЕ показывает мета-теги в коде страницы, а пишет один мета-тег:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
```

данная проблема решается путем добавления мета-тега:

```
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
```